# What is difference between authorization section and PrincipalPermissionAttribute?

Tags: asp.net

What is difference? What is the best?

V1:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Role="MyRole")]  
public class MyPage: Page
{}
```

V2:

`<authorization>
<allow roles="MyRole" />
</authorization>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those seem to be 2 unrelated/non-comparable things.

According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx, that attribute is used to limit which users can execute code.

Element `authorization` in web.config is to limit which [browser] users can access URL's that the website serves content for.

You wouldn't normally want that attribute in your asp.net app, anywhere, ever - if for anything else, then because your web app is executed by a single user account (app pool user), and unless you're impersonating some other users to access some resources, you'll never even have an opportunity to use that (even then). I see how that attribute might be useful in some desktop apps, maybe.

EDIT: Small addition/correction/clarification: I guess if you use windows authentication, and `<identity impersonate="true"/>` in web.config as a way to execute code on behalf of **windows** user accounts, then that attribute can possibly be used to protect usage/invocation of certain classes/methods - but we normally/alternatively still use `authorization` in web.config to protect access to url's for certain user groups, and conditionals to enable/disable features for certain user groups. Even though I think I now understand the purpose of that attribute, I doubt I'd ever be tempted to use it [even] in this scenario (win-auth + impersonation). +1

Comment: I don't use Windows Authentication, I use Forms authentication. When I use RoleProvider, attribute PrincipalPermission works correctly. Apparently, current thread is initialized with IPrincipal with roles from RoleProvider. I plan to use PrincipalPermissionAttribute in order to avoid hardcoding of role names. But I don't know Is it normally? Is it correct?